# Generate JNLP dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, jnlp, java-web-start

I need to pass argument to JNLP dynamically for which I tried using a servlet which extends `JnlpDownloadServlet` and then includes a jsp which has all the JNLP XML written into it.

But when I invoke the downloaded JNLP I get `BadFieldException`.

### Servlet

```
public class TestServlet extends JnlpDownloadServlet {  
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)  throws ServletException, IOException {  
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
res.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/jnlp.jsp").include(request, res);  
}
```

### jnlp.jsp

Used for dumping dynamic JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase=<%=request.getScheme() + "://"+ request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()+ request.getContextPath() + "/" %> href="test.jnlp">
  <information>
   <title>Demo</title>
   <vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</vendor>
  </information>
  <security>
   <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
   <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
   <jar href="lib/test.jar" main="true" />
  </resources>
  <application-desc name="Dynamic Tree Demo Application" main-class="org.Test" width="300"   height="300">
       <argument><%=request.getParameter("arg1")%></argument>  
       <argument><%=request.getParameter("arg2")%></argument>
  </application-desc>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

I cannot see the request parameters being received correctly in downloaded JNLP but the above `request.getScheme` and `request.getServerName` seem to be working fine. Because of argument value not being received correctly I get `BadFieldException` when JNLP tries to execute.

How to solve this?

Comment: actually it's even harder as you need to include the jnlp in the jar later (for signed jars), so the jar has to be signed dynamically too

Comment: Are you sure you are using the arguments in the call?
Could you provide the url you are using to download the jnlp?

Comment: I don't intend to include jnlp in the jar again, it works fine without that.

Comment: I am trying to do the same on Struts. Can you give me an idea as to how your **web.xml** and **struts-config.xml** should look like?

Comment: In my case, as I extend JnlpDownloadServlet class, there is a run time exception thrown which says     SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet     JnlpDownloadServlet
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet. Any idea why this may happen? I am using jnlp-servlet.jar, jnlp.jar and jardiff.jar from Java Samples and Demos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logically, `href="test.jnlp"` should be something like `href="test.jnlp?arg1=blah&arg2=tah"`.

AFAIU the JWS client will reach back to the server using the exact `coodebase`/`href` stated in the JNLP.

Also, definitely listen to what bestsss has to say.

Comment: and how exactly will I read these values in `<argument>` tag later even if I modify my `href`, How should my JSP be modified in order to cater to that.

Comment: It is still not working. Can you please tell me what should be contents of my test.jnlp posted at the server.

Comment: I don't agree, is not the href where the arguments should be added, but the url used to download the jnlp in the first place. Example: www.example.com/app/servlet/TestServlet?arg1=blah&arg2=tah

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the answer it helped me understand JNLP better and find a solution which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to old for being useful but I actually patched the Sun servlet code. There is a Class JnlpFileHandler where the actual substitutions are done.... Just saying... ;-)  If anyone is interested I can give you the code including a little explanation. I did not waste too much tima at it but all I can say is that I truly hope the rest of SUN's code is written in a LOT more respect to OO principles...

Comment: I recently did a mod of that code too; it works really well for my needs.