# Parsing Error JNLP 'request.getParameter'

Tags: java, parsing, jnlp

I create a JNLP file and I want to launch a jar file with two parameters (dynamic)

I am using `<%= request.getParameter("mac") %>` But I do not know why I have this error `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 20;`, the error is on the `<%=`.

This is my JNLP file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localmaite/jnlp/" href="Putty.jnlp">

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="maite.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="main.Main">
        <argument><%= request.getParameter("mac") %></argument>
        <argument><%= request.getParameter("port") %></argument>
    </application-desc>

</jnlp>
```

And with this error, I cannot execute my jnlp file.

Someone have already this type of error ? Does someone know why I have this error ?

Full message error (In french):

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 20; Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.startOfMarkup(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

PS : Sorry for my english but it is not my main language.

Comment: @dragon66 : I added it in the first message

Comment: Did you create your jnlp file dynamically? If not, I guess the <%= request.getParameter("mac") %> was not replaced by the correct content.

Comment: @dragon66 : no I do not create dynamically the jnlp file. I would like to pass argument to a jnlp file (dynamically, the arguments will change). How can I do ? I have to generate a jnlp file dynamicaly all time ?

Comment: I think so. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038773/generate-jnlp-dynamically

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).