# set param value of jnlp dynamically

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I am trying to launch applet using JNLP. I want to pass some parameter dynamically to applet. My JNLP file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/WebAppTest/jar/" href="">
        <information>
            <title>JNLP Test</title>
            <vendor>Java</vendor>
        </information> 
        <resources>
            <!-- Application Resources -->
            <j2se version="1.5+" />
            <jar href="test.jar" main="true" />            
        </resources>
        <security>
            <all-permissions/>
        </security>
        <applet-desc 
             name="Test Applet"
             main-class="com.test.TestApplet.class"
             width="100"
             height="30">
             <param name="testStr" value="something" />
        </applet-desc>
        <update check="background"/>
    </jnlp>
```

I want to set **testStr** value dynamically.

Comment: This might give an idea if you haven't got here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721587/pass-dynamic-params-via-jnlp

Comment: I go through from above link but how i get the request object  in .jnlp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant get Request object in jnlp file directly, So as an alternate make jnlp as a jsp page and pass the request and response to it as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038773/generate-jnlp-dynamically)  - and change the content type to application/x-java-jnlp-file as they did.

one more link http://portal.krypthonas.de/2010/10/11/passing-dynamically-parameters-to-a-java-web-start-app-jnlp/ with complete code snippets.