# How to pass arguments to JNLP launched Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, servlets, java-web-start, jnlp

I need to open a Java Swing application at client side on calling a servlet. Few arguments are also required to be received at the main method of that Swing application which gets opened via JNLP at a client browser. In my case the swing app is getting opened but no arguments are be received in anyway.

My JNLP file is not dynamically built. It is a static file. Here it is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
      codebase="http://localhost:8085/TestWebApp" 
      href="ContactEditor.jnlp">

    <information>
        <title>JNLP Example</title>
        <vendor>Catalyst Software</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8085/TestWebApp" />
        <description>JNLP Testing</description>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="ContactEditor.jar" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="my.contacteditor.ContactEditorUI">
        <argument>00001</argument>
        <argument>Harish Prasad</argument>
        <argument>220153429088</argument>
    </application-desc>    

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

</jnlp>
```

Please suggest how to pass arguments dynamically from the servlet to the swing application.

My questions are:

1. What code do I have to write at my Swing program?
2. What do I have to mention in the JNLP file?
3. How should I pass the values from the servlet?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). Note that JNLP above has two `<security>` elements..

Answer (score 2):

1. The [*JNLP File Syntax*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) specifies that "Each argument contains (in order) an additional argument to be passed to `main`."

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
       for (String value : args) {
           …
       }
   }
   ```
2. Your `<argument>`syntax appears correct, as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#application_desc); the `<security>` element appears twice, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577862/how-to-pass-arguments-to-jnlp-launched-swing-application/39579882?noredirect=1#comment66477012_39579882); verify the syntax as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577862/how-to-pass-arguments-to-jnlp-launched-swing-application/39579882?noredirect=1#comment66476974_39577862) by @AndrewThompson.
3. You'll need to construct the JNLP file dynamically, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11038773/230513).

Comment: *"syntax appears correct"* The `<security>` element appears twice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thank you for critical review; I was too focused on the `<argument>` syntax. Thanks also for linking to `JaNeLA`. Is there a canonical Q&A that cites it? I'd be happy to edit broken links if you see fit.

Comment: *"Is there a canonical Q&A that cites it?"* Most of my canonical Q&As have been (heavily upvoted but) closed. Afraid that one would attract accusations of 'spam'. :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson: [Hypnotoad](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Hypnotoad) suggests, "Some of the tools formerly available at my pscode.org domain can be downloaded from my [Google Share Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0)."